# What should I change about my approach to this data structure/algorithm problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm practicing data structures & algorithms, and I came across a problem that I'm stuck on.

> *You have an input array that contains elements in format "product, amount sold, price." You need to return an array with all products sorted by the amount sold. If two products have the same amount sold, sort them by lowest price.*

The way I started to go about it is:

- Loop through the array, splitting elements by the comma
- Add product name and price to a products object where the amount sold is the key
- Keep track of the max amount sold
- Starting from max, and going to zero, if there's a product with that key, push the name and price onto my return array
- Return array

This at least gives me the products sorted by amount sold.  But it doesn't work when I have products that sold the same amount. If items sell the same amount, I'm not sure of an efficient way to sort them by price.

Anyone have a good idea of how to implement the price sort? Or a better way of solving this problem?

```js
const items = [
  'Chair, 100, 20',
  'Sofa, 70, 200',
  'Desk, 80, 120',
  'Table, 400, 300',
  'Fan, 10, 60',
  'Pillow, 40, 5',
  'Blanket, 40, 20',
  'Rug, 100, 200',
  'Mat, 2, 30',
  'Stool, 80, 40',
  'Comforter, 200, 250',
  'Recliner, 50, 350',
];

class Product {
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
const productList = (items) => {
  let returnArray = [];
  let products = {};
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let productItems = items[i].split(',');
    let product = new Product(productItems[0].trim(), productItems[2].trim());
    let orderAmt = parseInt(productItems[1].trim());

    products[orderAmt] = product;

    max = Math.max(max, productItems[1]);
  }

  while (max > 0) {
    if (products[max]) {
      returnArray.push(`${products[max].name}, ${max}, ${products[max].price}`);
    }
    max--;
  }
  return returnArray;
};

console.log(productList(items));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You already have it all. It is in front of you. The approach is correct. Just map each product's string version into an item that features all of a product's data. Then sort this product item array via `sort` and a custom compare function that compares first by *amount sold*, then (if equal) by *price* and finally (if equal again) by *name*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... the words from my [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469155/what-should-i-change-about-my-approach-to-this-data-structure-algorithm-problem#comment112233268_63469155) materialized into code ...

```js
const productItemList = [
  'Chair, 100, 20',
  'Sofa, 70, 200',
  'Desk, 80, 120',
  'Table, 400, 300',
  'Fan, 10, 60',
  'Pillow, 40, 5',
  'Blanket, 40, 20',
  'Rug, 100, 200',
  'Mat, 2, 30',
  'Stool, 80, 40',
  'Comforter, 200, 250',
  'Recliner, 50, 350',
];

function getProductItemListAlignedBySoldAmountPriceAndName(itemList) {
  function compareAlphaNumericalAscending(a, b) {
    return (((a < b) && -1) || ((a > b) && 1) || 0);
  }
  function compareAlphaNumericalDescending(a, b) {
    return (((a > b) && -1) || ((a < b) && 1) || 0);
  }
  function compareNames(a, b) {
    return (
      (a.localeCompare && b.localeCompare)
      ? a.localeCompare(b)
      : compareAlphaNumericalAscending(a, b)
    );
  }

  function compareProductItemsByAmountSoldPriceAndName(a, b) {
    return (
         compareAlphaNumericalDescending(a.sold, b.sold)
      || compareAlphaNumericalAscending(a.price, b.price)
      || compareNames(a.name, b.name)
    );
  }
  function createProductItem(template) {
    const [name, sold, price] = template.split(/\s*,\s*/);
    return {
      name,
      sold: parseInt(sold, 10),
      price: parseInt(price, 10),
      template
    };
  }
  function getProductItemTemplate(item) {
    return item.template;
  }

  return itemList
    .map(createProductItem)
    .sort(compareProductItemsByAmountSoldPriceAndName)
    .map(getProductItemTemplate);
}

console.log(getProductItemListAlignedBySoldAmountPriceAndName(productItemList));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

@Cineno28 ... as it can be read from the last lines of the above function, the original approach was already pointing into the right direction ...

1. map each product item's string template form into a real, key-value based, product item (keep the string template too).
2. sort temporary item array by comparing the corresponding property values to one another in their correct order (`sold`, `price`, `name`).
3. restore each product item's original form by mapping back the `template` property.